# How do I offer a generous gift to sweet-seeking wasps, bees, hornets, bumble-bees?

Tags: behaviour, wasps

I was having ice coffee and melon ice and after visiting the lavatory I saw that a wasp was having a good time with my already finished ice coffee.

Trying to begin the melon ice the wasp kindly insisted to take a first bite despite my insistence to not do that. 
Feeling generous, I offered the wasp the already accepted ice coffee, but despite my best efforts (Waving it in the correct direction so that it get the smell directly before its nose) it only flew uselessly in circles.

Is there any method to give those sweet-seekers a meal which they gratiously accept (and in effect save us the nuisance to shoo them away) ?

Comment: So... you're looking for something you can have on-hand that will entice wasps and bees to follow it so you don't have to swat at them?

Comment: Or present the already available stuff (sugar, ice, honey, sweets etc.) in a rather compelling fashion, yes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many scientific methods for that which are widely used in animal behavior studies, specifically in honey bees. Read <s>[this](http://www.beesource.com/point-of-view/adrian-wenner/training-bees-to-visit-a-feeding-station/)</s> [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160202002438/http://beesource.com/point-of-view/adrian-wenner/training-bees-to-visit-a-feeding-station/). If you search you can find similar for mice and rats also :P

Comment: Dead link, already. Care to summarize?